# Items and categories (1:N) How to get number of total and total active items per category in single SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

**items**

```
item_id
title
active = 1/0
```

**items_categories_map**

```
item_id
category_id
```

I need to get result

```
category_id
items_total (any value of items.active)
items_active (items.active = 1)
items_inactive (items.active = 0)
```

Is it possible to get such result in a single SQL query without using UNION?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a template such as the following...

```
COUNT(items.active) AS items_total,
SUM(items.active)   AS items_active,
SUM(1-items.active) AS items_inactive
```

Or when you have values that are not 1 or 0...

```
SUM(CASE WHEN items.active = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as items_inactive
```

Comment: If `active` can never be NULL, this could also do: `COUNT(NULLIF(items.active, 0)) AS items_active, COUNT(NULLIF(items.active, 1)) AS items_inactive`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Dems: if you want to group by **and** have grand total as well use:

```
select items.id
 , COUNT(items.active) AS items_total
 , SUM(ifnull(items.active,0)) AS items_active
 , SUM(1-ifnull(items.active,0)) AS items_inactive
FROM items
GROUP BY items.somefield WITH ROLLUP

+------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
| id   | items_total | items_active  | items_inactive |
+------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
| 1    | 2           | 1             | 1              |
| 2    | ....
| null |100          | 60            | 40             |<<- grand total
+------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
```

`with rollup` you'll get a grand total row at the bottom.

**ifnull needed?**
If items.active can be null, you'll need a `ifnull()` in there to prevent the sum from evaluating to null and messing up your result.

Comment: Your logic treats a NULL record as being Inactive.  If it's actually neither Active not Inactive, you'd need to move the `1-` part inside the IFNULL...  `SUM(ifnull(1-items.active,0))`

Comment: @dems, yes yes, shortcuts. You should really define field `active` as boolean not null default 0 (or 1) I know, I was just pointing out how to make sure your sums don't return null, It's up to you to make the assumptions and write code accordingly.

Comment: @Andriy M rolled back your changes and redid them, 'cause I was curious what the new rollback option would do.

Comment: It's perfectly fine. Actually I'm glad you've found my changes useful and worth redoing. So thanks for letting me know about that.